# Choosing values based on an order in a list using SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have data as follows:

```
USER_ID value  date         cost
001         A  01-01-2021     10
002         C  01-01-2021     11
001         D  01-02-2021     21
002         G  01-02-2021     23
001         H  01-03-2021     32
```

All I would like to do is determine which `value` happened 2nd and which `value` happened 3rd for each user. This can be determined by the `date`. After getting this, we also need the cost on those days.

Resulting table should be as follows:

```
USER_ID   second_val  third_val second_cost  third_cost
001                D          H          21          32
002                G         NA          23           0
```

Notice that `USER_ID 002` does not have a third value, this will then be treated as NA. Consequently, the cost for an NA val is 0.

Comment: Please tag with the database platform.  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using row_number() to select 3 and 4 but I cant get it to run

Comment: As a windows function @OldProgrammer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be enough:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEMP1 
AS 
SELECT USER_ID, value,  date, cost
  FROM (VALUES 
        ('001', 'A', '01-01-2021', 10),
        ('002', 'C', '01-01-2021', 11),
        ('001', 'D', '01-02-2021', 21),
        ('002', 'G', '01-02-2021', 23),
        ('001', 'H', '01-03-2021', 32)) t(USER_ID, value, date, cost);
               
SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID
     , IFNULL(NTH_VALUE(value, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY date), 'NA') AS second_val
     , IFNULL(NTH_VALUE(value, 3) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY date), 'NA') AS third_val
     , IFNULL(NTH_VALUE(cost, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY date), 0) AS second_cost
     , IFNULL(NTH_VALUE(cost, 3) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY date), 0) AS third_cost
  FROM TEMP1;
```